# How to get the frame or the center of a cell that's being dragged with iOS11's drag-n-drop APIs

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I found a method to get a cell's center when it's being dropped. But I want to know its center when I'm dragging it across the collectionView. Anybody knows how I can get it?

Or is there a better solution? What I want to achieve is to let a user drop one cell onto another to create folders, while also letting him reorder cells (in other words, the same behaviour as the Springboard in iOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

You can use one of the UICollectionViewDropDelegate methods.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal
```

In which you can call a location(in: UIView) method on a session object.

```
session.location(in: collectionView)
```

**Update**

The problem with this method is it gives you a location where your finger is, not the center of the cells preview.